# Applying the jQuery tablesort and re-numbering line item #'s

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, tablesorter

I need your help.

While I love this jQuery tablesorter plug-in, its only downfall is that my line numbers because out of sorts upon sorting another column. How would one renumber the line item #'s such that they would be in sequence. For example, if I were to click on the [First Name] column, the table becomes sorted as follows in the image below:

[image]

As you can clearly see, my numbers on the left are now out of sorts. How could delete and re-number the line item #'s in their proper sequence starting from (lowest to the highest integer).

Here is the markup in question:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myTable").tablesorter();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://my-script-hosting.googlecode.com/files/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
</script>

<table id="myTable" class="style1" border="1" cellspacing="1">
  <thead>
    <tr style="border-width: 1px; background-color: #C0C0C0">
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Due</th>
      <th>Web Site</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td>
      <td>$50.00</td>
      <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Bach</td>
      <td>Frank</td>
      <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td>
      <td>$50.00</td>
      <td>http://www.frank.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>Jason</td>
      <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td>
      <td>$100.00</td>
      <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Conway</td>
      <td>Tim</td>
      <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td>
      <td>$50.00</td>
      <td>http://www.timconway.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After completing sorting it will fire **[`sortEnd`](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#events)** event at that time update the numbering

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myTable").tablesorter().on("sortEnd", function() {
    $(this).find("tr:gt(0)").each(function(i) {
      $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text(i+1);         
    });
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://my-script-hosting.googlecode.com/files/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
</script>

<table id="myTable" class="style1" border="1" cellspacing="1">
  <thead>
    <tr style="border-width: 1px; background-color: #C0C0C0">
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Due</th>
      <th>Web Site</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td>
      <td>$50.00</td>
      <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Bach</td>
      <td>Frank</td>
      <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td>
      <td>$50.00</td>
      <td>http://www.frank.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>Jason</td>
      <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td>
      <td>$100.00</td>
      <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Conway</td>
      <td>Tim</td>
      <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td>
      <td>$50.00</td>
      <td>http://www.timconway.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You just beat me to it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the sortEnd event and add some code to re-number the first column:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter().bind("sortEnd",function(e, t){
            var table = $(this);
            table.find('tbody tr').each(function(i){
                var row = $(this);
                var firstCell = row.find('td:first-child');
                firstCell.text(i+1);
            });
        });
    } 
);
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gdxjvtkm/